# In zend pass values to view by concating array in controller

Tags: php, foreach, zend-form-element

I have below array where I am getting this array by executing an MySQL query in zend.
I want to concatenate all the octent and get the result as 131.208.0.0 and 141.128.0.0 to pass to view to display.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [octet1] => 131
            [octet2] => 208
            [octet3] => 0
            [octet4] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [octet1] => 141
            [octet2] => 128
            [octet3] => 0
            [octet4] => 0
        )
)
```

With the below foreach I get all ailments how do i concatenate each octent for an array.

```
 foreach($arr as $external)
       {
            foreach ($external as $octent)
            {
                echo $octent."<br />";
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function is what you are searching for:

```
 $results = array();
 foreach($arr as $external){
       $results[] = implode('.', $external);
 }

 print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to work with the individual octets and have access to the query for modification, you could just retrieve `CONCAT(octet1, '.', octet2, '.', octet3, '.', octet4)` in the `SELECT` clause.

Otherwise you can just do this :

```
// array_map applies a function to every element of an array
$concatenated_arr = array_map(function($e) { return implode('.', $e); }, $arr);
```